# HTML email Template footer issue

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone

### I am creating **Email Template** and footer is not display proper  only on iphone's portrait mode. it is not in 100% width.

---

This the code and footer is meshed up on **iphone's mail..**
Please give me solution for this...

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1791KTM_aTog1Os_IpD41CFZLqQKfT7TQ

in this image footer is fine but iphone it only comes with 70% of width.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 body {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
  border: 10px solid #f0f0f0 !important
 }
 table.main {
  width: 340px !important;
  margin: 0 auto
 }
 table {
  display: block !important;
  width: 100%
 }
 table td {
  display: block;
  width: 100%
 }
 td {
  width: 100% !important;
  text-align: left !important;
  padding: 10px 0 0 0 !important
 }
 p {
  text-align: left !important
 }
 h2 {
  text-align: left !important
 }
 h3 {
  text-align: left !important
 }
 h4 {
  text-align: left !important
 }
 table td table td {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0 !important
 }
 tr td:first-child hr {
  display: none
 }
 table.main_table br {
  display: none
 }
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Email Template</title>
<body style="background-color: #f0f0f0; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom:20px;">
   <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="20" width="600" class="main" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding: 0;background:#fff;">
      <tr>
         <td>
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="margin-bottom: 15px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; padding-bottom: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
               <tr>
                  <td rowspan="2" style="width: 220px;"><img src="https://www.trimarkpremier.com/images/email/trimarkLogo.jpg"></td>
                  <td align="right" style="padding-top: 10px; color: #A9273D; font-size: 11px; font-family: 'open sans light', sans-serif;"> <a href="http://www.trimarkusa.com/about-trimark" target="_blank" title="About Us" style="font-size: 11px;color: #394EA1;text-decoration: underline;font-family: 'open sans light', sans-serif;">About Us </a>| <a href="http://trimarkusa.1kcloud.com/edlv_v9Sez/" target="_blank" title="Interactive Catalog" style="font-size: 11px;color: #394EA1;text-decoration: underline;font-family: 'open sans light', sans-serif;">Interactive Catalog </a>| <a href=" http://trimarkpremier.com/insights-resources" target="_blank" title="Insights & Resources" style="font-size: 11px;color: #394EA1;text-decoration: underline;font-family: 'open sans light', sans-serif;">Insights & Resources </a>| <a href="http://trimarkpremier.com/contact-us" target="_blank" title="Contact Us" style="font-size: 11px;color: #394EA1;text-decoration: underline;font-family: 'open sans light', sans-serif;">Contact Us</a></td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style=" font-family: 'Open Sans', sans serif; background:#fff;">
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="color: #A9273D; font-family: 'Open Sans', sans serif; background:#fff;">
                        <tr>
                           <td align="center" style="text-align: center !important; border-top: 1px solid #ccc; padding-top:15px;">
                              <p style="text-align: center !important;">
                                 <img src="http://trimarkpremier.com/images/email/footer_logo.png" style="text-align: center; margin: 0;">
                              </p>
                              <a href="https://www.trimarkpremier.com" style="color: #394EA1; font-size: 12px; font-family: Open Sans, sans serif; text-decoration: underline;">www.trimarkpremier.com </a>|<a href="mailto:info@trimarkpremier.com" style="color: #394EA1; font-size: 12px; font-family: Open Sans, sans serif; text-decoration: underline;"> info@trimarkpremier.com</a>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                     </table>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</body>
```

Comment: you should add your code so people can help you!

Comment: I posted my code "Alaa Mh".... Thank you for suggestion.
Actually i m fresher, so thank you again.

Comment: check the answer below

Comment: also FYI, using `!important` many times could break your design sometimes, try to avoid using it as much as you can since it's not preferable to be used, Search for **CSS specificity hierarchy** and learn more about it so you can avoid the use of `!important`.

Comment: Yeah sure... Thanx